# How to create a schematic for non js framework?

Tags: python, fastapi, nrwl

what is the best approach to start and create a new schematic in the nx repository?

I wanted to give it a try and work on [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) schematics, but cant really figure out how to setup the schematics.

Kind regards,

Stiil

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to start is the [Workspace schematics docs page](https://nx.dev/angular/workspace/schematics/workspace-schematics).

Now obviously that's for JS (Angular/React/...) but it guides you through the process.

To generate schematics for FastAPI, you'd mostly rely in writing files etc. So that works the same way. The only "downside" would be that you cannot really benefit from the AST utils that are in place for modifying/updating JS files.